# can i uninstall my app during run time of the application

Tags: android

I want to uninstall my app during run time programmatically when certain conditions match. Is it possible? I have read this but it is not working.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, Uri.fromParts("package",
getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(apkUri.getPath(), 0).packageName,null));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `:` after package

```
    public static void launchUnInstaller(Context ctx, String packageName) {
    try {
        Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" + packageName);
        Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
        ctx.startActivity(uninstallIntent);
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        Log.e(TAG,e.toString);

    }
}
```